# How to stop spawning attackers after a certain time?

Tags: c#

How can i stop spawning enemies after a certain time? The basic idea is that my enemies will spawn randomly, and i need some way to stop them from spawning after a certain time.

Below is my code:

```
[SerializeField] float minSpawnDelay = 1f;
[SerializeField] float maxSpawnDelay = 5f;
[SerializeField] Attacker[] attackerPrefabArray;
[SerializeField] float spawnerDelay = 1f;



bool spawn = true;

IEnumerator Start()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnerDelay);

    while (spawn)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(minSpawnDelay, maxSpawnDelay));
        SpawnAttacker();                
    }

}


public void StopSpawning()
{
   spawn = false;
}

private void SpawnAttacker()
{
    var attackerIndex = Random.Range(0, attackerPrefabArray.Length);
    Spawn(attackerPrefabArray[attackerIndex]);
}

private void Spawn(Attacker myAttacker)
{
    Attacker newAttacker = Instantiate
        (myAttacker, transform.position, transform.rotation)
        as Attacker;
    newAttacker.transform.parent = transform;
}
```

Comment: Can't you just call `StopSpawning()` with a timer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer for that purpose:

```
// Enemies will spawn for 5 seconds.
private float spawnTimer = 5f;

private void Update()
{
    if (spawnTimer > 0)
    {
        spawnTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (spawnTimer <= 0)
        {
            StopSpawning();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

The IEnumerator is always used for this purpose . The WaitForSeconds(timespan) is used when the event is being being triggered after a spefic timespan . Just use the below code and write your desried function after the "yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);" and it will trigger or run you desired function.

```
IEnumerator Example()
    {
        print(Time.time);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
         StopSpawning(enter code here); //your function 
        print(Time.time);
    }
```